# HTML5 Video wont validate

Tags: html, validation, video, embed

I was originally using embedded Youtube videos for this project I'm working on; however, I couldn't get validation to work, so I thought I'd try the HTML5 video stuff out.  I seem to be having trouble with it too: if you try to validate this code you get some weird errors:

> http://pastie.org/3892548

I put the code in there.  I get errors like:

- "there is no attribute "width"
- "there is no attribute "height"
- "there is no attribute "controls"
- "element "video" undefined"

I think you'd see it better for yourself though.  Thanks guys, I'm really struggling with this so any help as to why it's happening, and I might be able to fix it!  Thanks!

Edit thanks guys it was the doctype, however for maximum marks i need no errors or warnings, and i cant see why these are happening; http://puu.sh/u7O1

I tried adding the character encoding line back in but no joy

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If you're trying to validate code using HTML5 video, having it actually be HTML5 would help. Get rid of that and replace with

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for that, i now face these errors, i will try adding the encoding back in :) http://puu.sh/u7O1

Comment: Either add `Content-Type` header, or use a `meta` element, like this: `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`. I would not use the `<?xml>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the html5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
```

That doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional as you can see. The html5 doctype is much much shorter

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks i completely forgot about that! However now i have tentatively passed with these results; http://puu.sh/u7O1